# Google API oauth2 - how to store credentials in order ot refresh token later

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, token, google-api-python-client

I'm a super noob in python and oauth2 but still I've wasted days on this one, so if you guys could give me hand, I would be eternally grateful :')

Goal: writing a script that download a file everything 5min from google drive
Achieved: Get the credentials with tokens and download it once
**Problem: how do I refresh the token?**

I achieved to get my tokens once but I don't understand what to do so that I don't need to rebuild a refresh token eveytime...

I don't really know if I'm getting oauth2 wrong, but I've read that it should be stored and (there is store method, right?)

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, found it myself.

You gotta refresh you token everytime it expires, using httplib2.

Quick hint:
import httplib2
http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)

where credentials contains what you got from your first authorization flow.

Cheers